# How to depend on local directory for setuptools unit tests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, dependencies, setuptools

I want to develop two packages A and B in parallel, and B depends on A. I need to import something from A when running my unit tests for B.

So how can I configure things in setup.py so that when I run the unit tests for B, the local directory (in parallel to the one for B) gets added to the modules path and A can be imported?

I do not constantly want to install A so that B can depend on it like on an installed package.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think this is actually quite easy and I was thinking to complicated: I made it work by just setting PYTHONPATH to the relative path to the directory containing package A.